# Order of operations with multiplication, subtraction, and division in Java?

Tags: java

Below is the code and I wanted to know why it gives an output of `2.0` instead of `0.0`?

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 5*4/2 - 5/2*4;
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do _you_ think it should be 0.0?

Comment: In Java numbers are integers, unless they contain decimal dot, or `d` or `f` suffix... Thus the above computation is (5*4=20)/2=10 and (5/2=2)*4=8...

Answer (score 2):

Because 5/2 is 2 not 2.5. 5 and 2 is integer and / operator generates int.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division truncates any decimal places. You are probably expecting 5/2*4 to equal 10, but it is actually resolving to 8.

This can be solved by writing your numbers like this: 
`double x = 5.0*4.0/2.0 - 5.0/2.0*4.0;`

Simply storing the result in a double does not force the actual arithmetic to consider the values to be doubles.

Comment: You only need to write one number with .0 to force this behaviour on the "/" operator. Also, if you use Double instead of double, it won't even compile. Primitive types..

Answer (score 0):

You're working with integers. So `5/2*4` equals 8.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication and division have higher precedence than addition and subtraction, but the same precedence as each other. Multiplication and division operators are evaluated from left to right.

Evaluation proceeds from left to right, respecting precedence

The types used in an arithmetic operation depend only on the arguments to that operation. Storing the result in a double implicitly converts the result to a double, but that only happens *after* all of the arithmetic is complete.

Putting all that together our calculation looks like

- 5 * 4 -> 20
- 20 / 2 -> 10
- 5 / 2 -> 2 (these are integers, so it can't be 2.5)
- 2 * 4 -> 8
- 10 - 8 -> 2
- 2 -> 2.0 (implicitly convert result to double)